# API Rest with Hyperledger Fabric and node js Heroku

Tags: heroku, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to connect my Hyperledger Fabric network with my backend in Heroku.
I did all the connections as the examples suggest. This is how my code looks like:
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6kQB.png)

When I deploy to Heroku I get the following error:
 **[NetworkConfig101.js]: NetworkConfig101 - problem reading the PEM file :: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory**

My .pem files are in the same folder as my configuration file. [folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khhQD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using a path from working dir. For example, your tree structure dir:

```
.
├── app.js
└── artifacts
    ├── crypto-config
    │   ├── ca.crt
    │   └── key.pem
    └── network-config.yaml
```

In network-config.yaml, you should use path:

```yaml
path: ./artifacts/crypto-config/ca.crt
```

Another way is using absolute path.

```yaml
path: /data/app/artifacts/crypto-config/ca.crt
```